# How to NOT execute trigger while constructing object

Tags: perl, moo

I have this code:

```
package Foo;
use Moo;

has attr => ( is => "rw", trigger => 1 );

sub _trigger_attr 
    { print "trigger! value:". shift->attr ."\n" }


package main;
use Foo;

my $foo = Foo->new( attr => 1 );
$foo->attr( 2 );
```

It returns:

```
$ perl test.pl
trigger! value:1
trigger! value:2
```

This is default, documented behavior of Triggers in Moo.

How can I disable trigger execution if the attribute is set via constructor?

Of course I can do it like this:

```
package Foo;
use Moo;

has attr        => ( is => "rw", trigger => 1 );
has useTriggers => ( is => "rw", default => 0 );

sub _trigger_attr 
{ 
    my $self = shift;
    print "trigger! value:". $self->attr ."\n" if $self->useTriggers 
}

package main;
use Foo;

my $foo = Foo->new( attr => 1 );
$foo->useTriggers( 1 );
$foo->attr( 2 );
```

And get:

```
$ perl testt.pl
trigger! value:2
```

So it works, but ... it feels wrong ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know much about `Moo`, but in `Moose` you can implement your own code after the constructor. If you can do something like this in `Moo` it would give you the desired effect.

```
sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;

    # Sets "useTriggers" AFTER the object is already constructed.
    $self->useTriggers(1);
};
```

This would cause `useTriggers` to be set just after construction so the trigger would be active after the object is constructed, but not before it is constructed.

So you should be able to write:

```
my $foo->new(attr => 1);
$foo->attr(2);
```

And get the same output.

Comment: In Moo I get: `Can't call method "useTriggers" on unblessed reference`

Comment: hmmm, maybe try using the BUILD subroutine instead? get rid of `BUILDARGS` and try adding `sub BUILD { my $self = shift; $self->useTriggers(1); }`. Again, I'm not sure if this will act differently in `Moo` than it does in `Moose`.

Comment: Try the new code in the edited answer and let me know if it works. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
package Foo;
use Moo;

has attr => ( accessor => '_attr' );

sub attr { 
    my $self = shift;
    my $rv = $self->_attr(@_);
    print "trigger! value: ", $rv if @_;
    return $rv;
}


package main;
use Foo;

my $foo = Foo->new( attr => 1 );
$foo->attr( 2 );
```

Comment: If you have many such attributes, you can write a sub to generate the public accessor (and maybe even the attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Because Perl 5.36 was released with signatures no longer being experimental things got complicated in `Moose` ecosystem.

For `Moo` nothing changes, this useTriggers trick or building custom accessors stay as valid answers.

For `Moose` and `Mouse` when value was changed through attribute accessor old value was also passed. So trigger called from constructor and trigger called on existing attribute were distinguishable by arity. Common pattern was:

```perl
sub _change_attribute {
    my ( $self, $new ) = @_;

    return unless int @_ == 3;    # no old value, we're in constructor

    do something...
```

With signatures there is new issue - one cannot inspect `@_` if signatures are used (this is consider experimental, throws a warning and is generally discouraged). So one may fall into this trap when adapting signature to variable trigger sub arity:

```perl
sub _change_attribute ( $self, $new, $old = undef ) {

    return unless defined $old;

    do something...
}
```

This will work **only** if attribute itself cannot be `Undef`. Otherwise trigger will not work as expected on

- `$object->attribute( undef );`
- `$object->attribute( 123 );`    # ooops !

change.

The hacky solution is to **mistype old param on purpose as slurpy array**:

```perl
sub _change_attribute ( $self, $new, @old ) {

    return unless @old;   # no old value, we're in constructor

    do something...
}
```

This will fire properly when value is changed through attribute accessor (does not matter if attribute can be `Undef`) and will fire and skip logic when initialized from constructor.